# blitting with mapltolib does not work from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Trying to use blitting inside a jupyter notebook does not update the figure, only the first image is shown instead of the animation updating the figure.

Blitting as defined in the matplotlib documentation https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html

The notebook can be downloaded from [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/_downloads/d02cc2ec62705926879bef2873a94cc1/blitting.ipynb)

Do you know if there is a possibility to make that work ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you know if the animation renders into Jupyter without blitting? In my environment it does not. The only way I can animate inside Jupyter is by running `%matplotlib tk` (which requires the `tkinter` package), which opens an external window...

Comment: Using %matplotlib inline, it renders only the figure on the first "step" of the animation.
Using %matplotlib widget, it renders at every frame a new empty figure
Opening in a new window is not really the desired option to have that

Comment: The second sentence of that documentation says the animation and widget classes already use blitting and so when running examples using those in a Jupyter notebook you'd already have this. Is you purpose to make an animation or see blitting in action? I have several types of animations using matplotlib demonstrated [here](https://github.com/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder). Go there and press `launch binder` & a session will spin up. I couldn't tell you offhand which approaches are using blitting. Or possibly with some Jupyter examples you'll see how to alter the code to do what you want?

Comment: Hey, yes you are right, thanks for the examples.
Doing these animations is exactly what I need !
blitting is not a thing one needs in jupyter notebooks